# Is there a port for KStem for .NET?

Tags: lucene.net, stemming

I'm about to launch into a Lucene.NET implementation and I am concerned about using the `PorterStemFilter`.  Reading here, and reading source code, it appears to be far, far too aggressive for my needs.

I need something simpler that doesn't look for roots but just removes "er", "ed", "s", etc suffixes. From what I've read, KStem would do the trick.

I can't for the life of me find a .NET version of KStem.  I can't even find source code for the Java version to handroll a port.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Looks like it is easy enough to handcraft a reduced PorterStemmer by simply removing steps I don't want.  Anyone have success with that?

Comment: the java source for KStem are available at: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/

Comment: Any experience to compare using PorterStemmer and KStemmer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HunspellStemmer](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/tree/trunk/src/contrib/Analyzers/Hunspell), part of contrib. It can use freely available hunspell dictionaries to provide proper stemming.